# Backup the UEFI NVRAM entries in Linux

Tags: linux, backup, uefi

Is there any way to backup the UEFI NVRAM entries in Linux? (seem impossible as per https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1216104#p1216104, but want to confirm).

My EFI menu has duplicate entries, I want to remove them but need to be safe first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the post to which you linked. I've not heard of any EFI NVRAM backup utility since I wrote that post a bit over a year ago. Such a utility *could* be written -- it really shouldn't be that hard. AFAIK, it simply hasn't been written, though.